# jQuery .submit() not triggering on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I've looked at many of the questions on SO concerning this issue, and my problem is still not resolved. I am trying to have a text input and a submit input, and alert the value in the text field when the form is submitted. I am using jQuery's submit(), but it never triggers. I have created a simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="chat">
    <input id="chattext" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#chat').submit(function(e){
        var message = $('#chattext').val();
        alert(message);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to do this without a workaround? I know that there are ways to accomplish this without submit(), but I would like to use that method or at least understand what the problem is.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lad8N/

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/pvPvF/ . If you're running this without a proper webserver you need to add `https://` to the jQuery link instead of just `//`

Comment: If you open the console, does it show any error?

Comment: Are you able to access ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js?

Comment: @adeneo Thank you... that was the problem

Comment: @SpencerMoran - There you go, you should probably consider using something like WAMP, XXAMP, EasyPHP etc when developing, it makes things a lot easier.